# SqlException was unhandled by user code for cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()

Tags: c#, .net

I am new to .Net. I just started learning it. I came across as error, where it displays that "SqlException was unhandled by user code."

```
protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand();
    cmd.CommandText = "insert tbemp (@eno, @ename, @es, @eadd)";
    cmd.Connection = con;
    cmd.Parameters.Add("@eno",SqlDbType.Int).Value = Convert.ToInt32(TextBox1.Text);
    cmd.Parameters.Add("@ename", SqlDbType.VarChar,50).Value = TextBox2.Text;
    cmd.Parameters.Add("@es", SqlDbType.VarChar, 50).Value = TextBox3.Text;
    cmd.Parameters.Add("@eadd", SqlDbType.VarChar, 50).Value = TextBox4.Text;
    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
    cmd.Dispose();
    TextBox1.Text = String.Empty;
    TextBox2.Text = String.Empty;
    TextBox3.Text = String.Empty;
    TextBox4.Text = String.Empty;
    TextBox1.Focus();
}
```

Comment: https://www.tutorialspoint.com/sql/sql-insert-query.htm  SQL has structure, syntax and keywords.

Comment: Read [ask]. The exception has a very helpful message, indicating what is wrong with your query. Using that message, you can do research, doing which you can find a solution.

Answer (score 0):

Your insert DML is not correct. It should be: `insert into tbemp values(@eno, @ename, @es, @eadd)`.

I would also be very careful with your size limitations of 50 characters and a direct assignment of the TextBox-Values. It might be another exception source.

Answer (score 0):

The SQL query you are setting to `cmd.CommandText` is not valid SQL. Assuming `tbemp` is your table name, your query should look like:

```
insert into tbemp values (@eno, @ename, @es, @eadd)
```

Comment: I think we can add values without using into, if we are entering values in a single table. Moreover, I have tried with into as well, but no luck:(

Comment: Does your table have more columns than four? In this case, you might need to specify the columns for inserting explicitly, like: `insert into tbemp (column1, column2, column3, column4) values (@eno, @ename, @es, @eadd)`

Comment: And just fyi, INTO can not be omitted in T-SQL. Here are some helpful examples how to use INSERT INTO correctly that should get you further: https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd776381%28v=sql.105%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396

Answer (score 0):

I would do something like this:

```
using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand())
   {
      try
      {
        cmd.CommandText = 
        "INSERT tbemp VALUES (@eno, @ename, @es, @eadd)";
        cmd.Connection = con;
        cmd.Parameters.Add("@eno", SqlDbType.Int).Value = 
             Convert.ToInt32(TextBox1.Text);
        cmd.Parameters.Add("@ename", SqlDbType.VarChar, 50)
             .Value = TextBox2.Text;
        cmd.Parameters.Add("@es", SqlDbType.VarChar, 50).Value = 
             TextBox3.Text;
        cmd.Parameters.Add("@eadd", SqlDbType.VarChar, 50).Value = 
             TextBox4.Text;
                cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

        TextBox1.Text = String.Empty;
        TextBox2.Text = String.Empty;
        TextBox3.Text = String.Empty;
        TextBox4.Text = String.Empty;
        TextBox1.Focus();
      }
      catch (SqlException exception)
      {

          System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(exception.Message);
          throw;
      }
      catch (Exception exception)
      {
          System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine
            ("General Exception caught: " + exception.Message);
          throw;
      }
```

In the event of an exception, your SqlCommand will be disposed by putting it in a using statement.  Now you will also get diagnostic print out of the errors you are receiving too.  Also since you aren't doing anything with the Exception (like trying to fix the issue by a retry or something), you want to throw the exception, so that the code calling the method will know that something is wrong.  When rethrowing an exception, you don't want to do this `throw exception`, because that will reset the stack trace.  Just use `throw`.